# DNN Jquery not loaded

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

Hi I have a big problem with my DNN (DotNetNuke) website.  The problem is my image slider, it use jquery but the problem is jquery will be loaded after log-in and i don't know why.

In this screenshot I have the log-in:
[image]

In this screenshot I didn't log-in
[image: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/1135x388q90/908/86a6a4.png]

If the user is not logged in, jQuery will not load.

Version of DNN: `7.03`

Comment: Does the authenticated version of the page use a different template to the non-authenticated one? Have you applied authentication to whatever folder you're serving the script from?

Comment: Can you post some code showing jQuery being rendered to Html?

Comment: To me, your question is similar to asking a mechanic the following: When the keys are in my car, the radio doesn't work. Here is a picture of my car with the keys in, and here is a picture without. What's wrong with my car?

Comment: @DGibbs yes the version is the same, how i can apply autentication?